# Failed to publish build information on to IBM devOps Insights using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin, devops-insights

I have configured Jenkins to publish build information on to DevOps Insights.
I was able to verify the build frequency in DevOps Insights.
But i was not able to see the error logs.

Could you tell me, if below configuration will publish the error message on to DevOps Insights. Or do i need to do any other Configuration in Jenkins?

### Error

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
[IBM Cloud DevOps] version: 1.1.18
[IBM Cloud DevOps] Log in successfully, get the Bluemix token
[IBM Cloud DevOps] Error: Failed to upload, response status HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
[IBM Cloud DevOps] Reason: "Missing one of fields: repository_url,branch,commit_id."
[IBM Cloud DevOps] Not building Deployable Message.
Finished: FAILURE
```

### Configuration

Click [here](https://github.com/starlord-dixon/StackOverflow/blob/master/Ibm%20DevOps%20Build%20Publisher%20Configuration.PNG)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use it with the freestyle job to Publish Build Record, you will need to configure the Git source in SCM, so that the plugin can figure out the repository_url, branch and commit id